# file validation in linux scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file, where first column contains header (file Id, value1_id, value1_type, value2_id, value2_type). file Id contains file names and value_id contains file value and value_type contains data type. I need to pick each file and check for the dataype and see if correct datatype values are entered in value_id. I could have done in Python but it is required in Linux, and I tried below script but its not that what is needed

```sh
while IFS=':' read col1, col2,col3,col4
do
echo 'col1'|grep "^[0-9]*$"
val="$?"

if [[$val==0]]
then
echo "Integer"
exit
fi

echo $col2|grep "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
val="$?"

if [[ $val==0]]
then
echo "String"
exit
fi
done < /root/file.ext
```

Can anyone help with this, I'm very much unaware of linux scripting.

Comment: Python is available for Linux too. See [Python on Linux](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-linux) for a start.

Comment: Just about any modern Linux distribution will have python installed by default.

Comment: no we cant use python here because of some security concerns, it would require lot of approvals for installation and may not be approved have to use linux itself

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all syntax issues it points out.

Comment: Also, you should provide a [mcve] and describe how your code fails, specifically.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your suggestion, but code didnt fail actually, its like i'm not aware of how to do it.

Comment: `its not that what is needed` What you need then? Please be specific: `see if correct datatype values are entered in value_id` Please define "correct datatype values"? What are "datatypes"? What are "correct values" for each of these "datatypes"? You script `read col1, col2,col3,col4` and `[[$val==0]]` has many problems - check your script with http://shellcheck.net . And use `awk` anyway.

Comment: Hello, could you provide an example of your file and the desired output please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in pure bash, use the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  line=( ${line//[:]/ } )
  for i in "${!line[@]}"; do
    [ ! -z "${line[$i]##*[!0-9]*}" ] && printf "integer" || printf "string"
    [ "$i" -ne $(( ${#line[@]} - 1)) ] && printf ":" || echo
  done
done < $1
```

Pass your file as first argument.

This script iterates over all lines in file (`while read line; do ... done < $1`, where `$1` is the file path), then it replaces all colons in each line with spaces (`${line//[:]/ }`). A variable with values separated with spaces can be treated as an array, and that's why this substitution is in brackets.

Now we can iterate over all values in a line. For each index in the `line` array we:

1. Check if it contains digits only. It is done by removing all digits from current value in line (`${line[$i]##*[!0-9]*}`, where `line[$i]` is the current value) and then checking if it's empty (`! -z`). If it is, then we print `integer`, or otherwise `string`.
2. Check if this is not the last element in array. It is done by comparing current index (`$i`) with the array length (`${#line[@]}`) decreased by 1. If current index is not the last, we print `:`. Otherwise, we print new line.

This is done for all lines in a given file. Given an input file with the following content:

```
col1:col2:col3:col4
1:word:2:word2
word3:3:word4:4
```

We get the following result:

```
string:string:string:string
integer:string:integer:string
string:integer:string:integer
```

Answer (score 2):

You used IFS=':' in your example, so I assume fields are separated by ':' sign.

Let's imagine we have the following file called /root/file.ext :

```
col1:col2:col3:col4
1:word:2:word2
word3:3:word4:4
```

where the first line is the heading.

Then you can use the following command:

```
tail -n+2 /root/file.ext | awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ( match($i, /^[0-9]+$/) ) $i="integer"; else $i="string"} {print}}'
```

tail -n+2 will print the file without heading, pass output to awk and awk will do the validation resulting in the following output:

```
integer:string:integer:string
string:integer:string:integer
```